# run function from child window in parent window

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window

I have two windows: the `parent` and the `popup`. Obviously `parent` has a reference to `popup`. Now in `popup` I have a function say

```
function test() { alert('test'); }
```

and I want to call this function in `parent`, something like `popup.test();`. Is there a way to do that? I do know how to do that the other way around. Just declaring

```
window.test = function() { alert('test'); }
```

and calling `window.opener.test();` in popup works fine. However this does not work in my case (I think because the `window.opener` object is a reference, but `window.open` and `window` in `popup` are not really related). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the context where you defined the function for the popup window. Assuming you attached the functions/data to the `window` object of the popup window, you can access it from the window handle returned by `window.open` (the window handle *is* the `window` object for the popup):

```
var w = window.open(somelocation,''); //has a function on `window` called "test"
w.test();
```

<sub>I'm going to assume that you understand how security sandboxes work for popup windows</sub>

Comment: Actually the function is defined inside `popup`. I need to have access to popup's html.

Comment: Well, I suppose I can refactor my code so this solution will be good enough. :) I will mark your answer, thank you!

Comment: once you have access to the window handle, you can access the window's document at `w.document` which will allow you to call `w.document.getElementById` or any other function that you need. Do be careful with passing data between windows. An object in one window can act oddly in another depending the context in which it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `test()` in your popup as follows:

```
window["test"] = function()
{
  alert("It works!");
}
```

Then open your popup from your main window:

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", "The popup");
```

And call your function:

```
popup.window.test();
```

jsFiddle (won't work without the `/show` because of the cross-domain restriction!): http://jsfiddle.net/szK3F/show/

Comment: Are your URLs on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, they are. I'm using Chrome. Actually the `popup` has no URL at all. It is blank and the content is inserted via `popup.document.write`.