# Socket.IO chat in html popup window

Tags: jquery, node.js, popup, socket.io

I try making Socket.IO chat using generated popup window for private message.
I use windows.opener var in popup window code to acess variables and functions in main page. In Firefox and Chrome window.opener.socket.on(...) function successfully start from popup window code, but IE9 wont. Node.js server in background send and receive events. I use following code:

```
     //in index.php
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
     //other code
    $("#users .user").live('click',function(){
    //other code
    popUpWin[client_id]=window.open('private.php', client_id, 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbar=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,width=300,height=400,left=' + left + ', top=' + top + ',screenX=' + left + ',screenY=' + top + '');         
    //other code        
    });


    //in private.php
    //other code
    window.opener.socket.emit('popup',window.opener.client_id);//This work!         
    window.opener.socket.on('private_message', function (data) {This not work, private message event is send!
        $("#private_data_recieved").append('<div><b>'+data.nick+':</b> '+parseString(data.message)+'</div>');
        playSound();                        
    }); 
        //other code
```

Comment: You have the swf file as fallback?

Comment: In the same folder of your `socket.io.js` you should see a `WebSocketMain.swf` file

Comment: nothing like that, i install module with npm method

Comment: Please describe me how that .swf file can make be solution for my problem?

Comment: see my answer (I'm sorry but the official site of socket io is down now for me and I can't search the official answer :))

Comment: Ok sorry I did not realize that the first connection works. Any error reporting on IE9?

Comment: Nothing. Var socket in popup window is initalized  with some object when i use window.opener.socket, but window.opener.socket.on('private_message',function(){...}) not fired. Server send event i check that!

Comment: This is last thing for my chat app that not working, and i can resolve it.

Comment: I see nothing of wrong in your code... can you try to move your `on` function before the `.emit`? But I cannot guess without try. I should reproduce it with a small code and try

Comment: I everything try but nothing, smell like some IE9  bug :)

Comment: IE9 does not supports native websocket. Probably the socket.io library fallback on  `xhr-polling`. You can try to use another transports (https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does not supports native websocket. So the socket.io library do a fallback on xhr-polling  system. This cause some problem in IE (honestly for me unknown).

However if you change approach to the problem like so:

in index.php

```
var EVENT = module.exports.EVENT;
var socket = io.connect('http://78.46.135.87:8060');
var win;
socket.on('private_message',function(data) {
    win.receivedPrivate(data);
});

function openPrivate() {
    win =window.open('private.php', 1, 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbar=no,resizable=no,copyhistory=yes,width=300,height=400');         
}
function popupReady() {
     socket.emit('popup',"1");
}
// and html
<a href="#" onclick="openPrivate()">Open private</a>
```

in private.php

```
window.receivedPrivate = function(data) {
    $('#private_data_recieved').append(data);
}
window.opener.popupReady();
```

it should works. I moved the logical of socket in `index.php` leaving in `private.php` the view logical. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Not working :( Here is similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152829/run-function-from-child-window-in-parent-window ,

Comment: Can you upload your test on jsfiddle please?

Comment: Not working :( I have same problem here http://vlacky.site11.com/popup/ . Please tell me where is error?

Comment: Message in new window not appended,  i don't now why.

Comment: yes... in your code try to move `$(popUpWin).ready(function() {` in click handler

Comment: @user1477508 try now... I've added a function call for ready document (I think is that the problem) See the source of my link

Comment: Nothing like that not working in Firefox/Chrome/IE together. Finally, i just wont append some text from parent window in popup window (calling function in popup window), but nothing not working. Here is source with suggested changes: http://vlacky.site11.com/popup/

Comment: you call `popUpWin.window.receivedPrivate('Message');` after window.open but you should give the time for load content of private.php (indeed I got, in your page, the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'receivedPrivate' `. Please see my update answer and try it. Believe me: it works! :)