# JavaScript select element from another Window

Tags: javascript, web

Here is what I am trying to do: I have a functionality on a web page that can be opened in a new window(drag/drop elements into new locations), so there is a need to sync the data between two windows(mostly to trigger a refresh on a window whenever something was changed in another window)

So the question is is it possible to trigger a function of one window from a new window(preferably using jQuery) and vice versa?

**UPDATE:**

Both child and parent windows share the same JS file. So far I managed to call parent window function nameSpace.someFunction() just by calling it using window.opener.nameSpace.someFunction(). But how do I go the other way arround? How do I call the child window function from the parent window?

Comment: Yes it is, if both windows come from the same protocol, port and host. What have you tried to do so far? How are you opening the other window?

Comment: The web app is based on the zend platform and pages are generated by parsing Json feeds, so not sure even where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are still having a parent window - child window relationship, you can access/share child window's information from parent window and vice-versa.

Check here how to access child window's function from the parent

[run function from child window in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152829/run-function-from-child-window-in-parent-window)

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to look into the HTML5 postMessage API

Comment: this is only required for cross domain access, you can access pop ups using vanilla javascript just fine.

Comment: You can do this without `postMessage`

Comment: Also not an actual answer - doesn't resolve the problem since the user isn't asking a question that is a valid s.o. question, hence comments to clarify and votes to close.